# Odoo 13 - json api giving invalid json data error

Tags: python, json, odoo, rest

Code -odoo 13 custom module

function to return data in json(rest api)

```
from odoo import http
from odoo.http import request, Response
import json


class OpenAcademy(http.Controller):
    @http.route('/opentest/', type='json', csrf=False, auth="none", methods=['GET'],)
    def update_order_webhook(self):

        return {
                'success': False,
                'error': 'no_tx_found',
            }
```

---

```
Error - <title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Invalid JSON data: ''</p>
```

Also returning content type as text/html, when i am clearly defining type="json"

Comment: Make your question more clear https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: The message is just because you send a bad Json format to Odoo. Could you show me the Json passed.

Answer (score 0):

you return dict...

try to return `json.dumps(your_dict)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide an empty request body.
I think this will solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

try type='http' if it works for you